# Counting instances of a parameter value on an access form

Tags: database, ms-access

I'd like to display, in the form footer of a Microsoft Access form, a count of a particular value of a field ("Category") I have tried using

```
=Sum(IIf([Category]="S",1,0))
```

as the control source for the text control in the footer, but this fails.  I cannot figure out why I cannot perform this calculation on this control/field combination. I suspect it has to do with "Category" not being the control source for any control, even though it's available in the second column of my combo box.

I have performed the count on the "Appliance" field instead, and the sum function works correctly, So I'm pretty sure my general syntax and references aren't completely broken. Both underlying values are text fields.

I'd love some help with how I can get to the second parameter of the query with the Sum function?

Specifics:

**ComboBox**
Name is "lstAppliance". Bound Column: 1 , Row source :

```
SELECT qryApplianceDetails.Appliance, qryApplianceDetails.Category FROM qryApplianceDetails;
```

**Text Box**
Name is "txtCategory" , Control Source:

```
=Appliance.Column(1)
```

In case this isn't clear enough, what I'd like to see looks something like this:

---

*Form header:*
Appliance , Category

---

*Form detail*

Truck , S
Truck , L
Car , S
Bike , M
House, L
Planet , S

---

*Form footer*
Number of "S" things: 3

---

With this source in the footer:

```
=Sum(IIf([Appliance]="Truck",1,0))
```

Displays "2", as you  would expect, but:

```
=Sum(IIf([Category]="S",1,0))
```

Displays "#error", instead of "3" as I'd expected.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something simpler, but not sure if this will be too simple for what you need.

Use this expression as the control source for txtCategory:

```
=DCount("*", "qryApplianceDetails", "Category='S'")
```

Then in the form's On Current and After Update events, add this:

```
Me.txtCategory.Requery
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is on a subform, so as mentioned by David-W-Fenton, I get the sum of Category for every record, not just those on the subform.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the issue of using a field in the form's recordsource in an expression (or in VBA code), since A2000, things have become more difficult. It's not reliable if the field you're using has not been used as the ControlSource of a control on your form. The workaround is to create an invisible control with the field as its ControlSource.

Another way of working around that problem would be to create a control with this ControlSource:

```
  =Val(IIf([Category]="S", 1, 0))
```

...then Sum() on that control.

I don't like the idea of using a DCount() as it requires a hit on the database for data that's already in the form. Secondly, if this is in a subform, the DCount() would need to be filtered not just on the Category value but also on whatever the link field is between the subform and its parent. It just gets so fussy that I'd say it's better to go with something that can be derived from the recordset already loaded in the form.

Comment: It is on a sub-form, as you mentioned, so the DCount() option is messy too.

I went with creating a separate control.  The numbers in the control were correct, but the Sum funtion didn't work.  I'm currently working on creating a separate funtion in VBA to calculate them all.

Comment: A field on a subform should still be accessible via an expression like `[Subformname].Form!Category`.